# getting two specific elements of a matrix

Tags: matlab, octave

Is there a shorthand to get specific elements out of a matrix? Say, I have a matrix `m`, and I want to get element `(a, b)` and `(c, d)`. Can I do this in a single expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another options (and in my view a simpler one) is just:

```
 val=[m(a,b) m(c,d)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use `sub2ind` to convert a list of subscripts to index. This works for any number of dimensions. From your example, if you want to get `matrix(a, b)` and `matrix(c, d)`, you can instead do:

```
values = matrix(sub2ind (size (matrix), [a c], [b d]))
```